# Is rendering of Advanced CSS3 always faster then Javascript/jQuery in any browser which has support for both?

Tags: javascript, css

Is rendering of Advanced CSS3 properties like CSS 3D, Web-kit Animations etc. always faster then Javascript/jQuery? or sometime even CSS 3 can be slower then JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on exactly what you're doing and how you're doing it, and probably on the browser...

Comment: I'm specially considering iphone Safari, Android Browser

Comment: Is **caching** also a thing to consider between javascript and css

Comment: Do you have any examples of JS+DOM being faster than CSS3?

Comment: Not offhand, but I would think that things like animating the position of one element with respect to another would be faster in JS+DOM because you can do them directly whereas in CSS you have to jump through contortions and probably animate multiple elements to achieve the same effect.  In any case, I would guess that using jQuery is the slowest of the options; the way it does its animations is pretty suboptimal performance-wise.